# nginx frontend server is not redirecting to apache backend

Tags: django, apache, redirect, ubuntu, nginx

I have a Ubuntu 13.04 virual machine with nginx frontend server and apache backend
serving a django project. Apache itself seems to work fine when operating separately
from nginx(and vice versa). But it looks like requests are not passed by nginx to
Apache when they work together.

After typing in my_host_name.com in the browser i get nginx "Welcome....!" page,
but it should be an apache-rendered page instead.

UPD: the *"Welcome..."* page appears only on first load, after the browser(chrome) is restarted(caching?), otherwise it returns just an empty page *("This webpage is not available* ..........  **Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** *")*. I get the same error page immediatly when accessing _my_domain_name.com_ from the host OS. I restart both servers(just in case) after each configuration change.

Typing in my_domain_name.com:8000 returns a correct apache response(static files 
excluded)

After a day of googling still can't find what's wrong.

My servers' settings are:

File: /etc/nginx/proxy_params

```
proxy_redirect              off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size        10m;
client_body_buffer_size     128k;
proxy_connect_timeout       90;
proxy_send_timeout          90;
proxy_read_timeout          90;
proxy_buffer_size           4k;
proxy_buffers               4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size  64k;
```

File: /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_domain_name

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domain_name.com;
    location / {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_settings;
    }
    location /static/ {
        root /path/to/my/project/root;
    }
    location /media/{
        root /path/to/my/project/root;
    }
}
```

File: /etc/apache2/sites-available/my_domain_name.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/root/django.wsgi

    ServerName my_domain_name.com


    <Directory /path/to/my/project/root>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname On
    RPAFproxy_ips  192.168.137.10 127.0.0.1
</VirtualHost>
```

File: /etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8000
Listen 8000
```

File: /etc/hosts

```
192.168.137.10 my_domain_name.com
127.0.0.1      my_domain_name.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're new to all of this, just use gunicorn. If you're already done with the project and not just starting, then you're going to have some tough luck.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, it feels like the problem is not with Apache(it is still serving fine when accessed directly via port 8000). Thanks for the advice anyway! I'll definetly try gunicorn, if there's no quick solution.

Comment: do you call `my_domain_name.com` or `www.my_domain_name.com` ? cause there's a difference

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, yes I call my_domain_name.com. In fact, changing it everywhere to www.my_domain_name.com makes no difference.

Comment: if you have the `default` symlink inside `sites_enabled` try deleting it and restarting nginx then see if it will work or not, just so we can understand the symptoms, or instead just make this server the default by doing `listen 80 default_server` and removing the default word from the current default server

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, my_site_name was already the only link in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/    `listen 80 default_server` changes nothing as well

Comment: The welcome page then makes no sense, it shouldn't be there by anyway, you do restart the server right ? and are you sure it's from nginx not from the python server?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, ooo I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that the _"Welcome..."_ page appears only on first load, after the browser(chrome) is restarted(caching?), otherwise it returns just an empty page_("This webpage is not available_ ..........**Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** "_)_. I get the same error page immediatly when accessing _my_domain_name.com_ from the host OS. I restart both servers(just in case) after each configuration change.

Comment: Paste your logs from nginx and apache.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid,  looks like _localhost.access.log_ file was not created at all in _/var/log/nginx_ and no new entries appear in _access.log_ or _error.log_ logs for both _/var/log/apache2_ and _/var/log/nginx_. (apache logging works fine, if apache is accessed direcly via port 8000 it is listening to) [link](http://pastebin.com/ZyA81DnR) - records to apache log are only added when it's accessed directly, records in nginx logs are obsolette/

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with my Nginx setup with my Apache back end, specifically when Apache was issuing a redirect for:

```
/some-location => /some-location/
```

Nginx was running on port 80, and my back end Apache on port 8000. and port 8000 was being passed onto the client in the 301 redirect.

It took a bit of playing, but I was able to get it to work.  Here is what I had to do:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8000;
   proxy_redirect  default;
   proxy_redirect  http://$host:8000/ http:/$host/;
   ... etc ..
}
```

Both Nginx and Apache virtual servers are using the same hostname (i.e. mydomain.com)